# python pattern detect and replace string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a question on Python string operation:

Here's a string in which there are multiple .(dot),

like:
`"a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g"`

The question is to find the content before the last .(dot), which is
`"a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f"` in this example (We call it as STRING_BEFORE_LAST_DOT)

and we need to replace STRING_BEFORE_LAST_DOT to be STRING_BEFORE_LAST_DOT + "_Approved".
So the result should be:
`"a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f_Approved.g"`.

And some more examples:

```
"a.b" -> "a_Approved.b"
"first.second.c" -> "first.second_Approved.c"
```

I can def a function to do so, I'm wondering if there's any advance way, like use .replace() to make it happen. Thanks.

Comment: apart from some fancy regex, you can also do this quite easily with `split` and `join`. Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Comment: @Ma0 Yeah, I tried to def a function (split by dot and reconnect the parts one by one). I know it's far away from a efficient solution, so come to ask for help..

Comment: That should not be too bad actually. Is performance so important for your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `join` + `rsplit` with a limit of 1:

```
>>> "_Approved.".join("a.b".rsplit(".",1))
'a_Approved.b'
>>> "_Approved.".join("first.second.c".rsplit(".",1))
'first.second_Approved.c'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# your String
string = 'a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g'
# find the last dot character in your string
StringIndex = string.rfind('.')
# create a temporary list of your string and swap the last dot with your preferred string (_Approved.)
temp = list(string)
temp[StringIndex] = '_Approved.'
# replace
string = ''.join(temp)
# print
print('Old String: a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g \nNew String: '+ string)

# OUTPUT
# Old String: a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g 
# New String: a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f_Approved.g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you can try out,

```
def _replace(input_):
    sub_ = input_[input_.rfind("."):]
    return input_.replace(sub_, f"_Approved{sub_}")


print(_replace("a.b"))
print(_replace("first.second.c"))
```

---

```
a_Approved.b
first.second_Approved.c
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do it with a regexp:

```
import re
s = "a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g" 
no_ext = re.split(r'\.[^\.]*$', s)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative. You can access every dot's index with this:

```
import re
str = "a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f"
# Finds every dot's starting index. (For ending of matched value d.end())
dots = [d.start(0) for d in re.finditer(r'\.+', str)]
# _Approved added
str = str[:dots[-1]] + "_Approved" + str[dots[-1]:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern to match from the last dot until the end of the string `.[^.]*$`

Then replace with _Approved and add the full match after it using `\g<0>`

```
print(re.sub(r"\.[^.]*$", r"_Approved\g<0>", "a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f.g"))
```

Output

```
a3a.b1b2b.cccc.ded.f_Approved.g
```